# Throwing Exception while sending Email to multiple recipients using smtp client

Tags: c#, email

I have an application which uses SmtpClient to send an email. I am trying to send an email to multiple recipients. I have two recipients in my to list e.g "aman@gmail.com,abc@xyz.com". and I am trying to send the email to this list but my application is throwing the exception as below:
**Client does not have permission to submit mail to this server. The server response was: 4.7.1 (abc@xyz.com): Relay access denied.**
because of this aman@gmail.com is also not able to receive the email.
I need to implement the functionality that even there is an invalid address like abc@xyz.com in the ToList, an email should be sent successfully to aman@gmail.com.
Can anybody please help me in this?

Comment: Can anybody please help. I need to implement the functionality that If I have send an email to multiple recipients, In Recipietns list I have some email address which does not exist and some email addresses are valid and exists, I need to send the email to the recipients email addresses which exists without any exception

Answer (score 3):

Does this error message come from your own email server, or from that of xyz.com? I'm guessing it's your own server, and that you either need to aunthenticate before sending, or use your own email address for sending (but the latter is kind of a long shot -- "we do not relay" means a server which is neither the sender's or the recipient's refuses to act as a middleman). It is also possible that the mail exchanger for xyz.com is misconfigured (either the MX record in DNS points to the wrong server, or the admin failed to configure it to accept this responsibility - technically basically the same thing) or that your client somehow ends up connecting to the wrong place.

(Not a proper answer but this got too long to fit in a comment.)

Comment: even though mail exchanger for xyz.com is misconfigured an email should be sent to aman@gmail.com. I have seen this functionality in Microsoft Outlook where I can recieve the email in my inbox(aman@gmail.com) successfully. and sender gets the delivery fail notification for abc@xyz.com.

Comment: Yes, that suggests to me that you are connecting to the wrong server, or fail to aunthenticate with an outbound server which requires authentication (but again, for the latter case, I would expect a more helpful error message; but too many mail servers were cobbled together by summer interns from the Seattle suburbs). Again, which server is rejecting your message?

Comment: xyz.com is throwing an exception. please find the below code for your reference:

Comment: @jolly: below what? Your answer was truncated or something. Probably best if you edit your question to incorporate the additional information.

Comment: SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient();       SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("IC007276", "CHE88**tan");
SmtpServer.Port = 25;SmtpServer.Host = "132.186.124.40";mail = new MailMessage(); mail.From = new MailAddress("aman@gmail.com", "aman", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
mail.To.Add("aman@gmail.com,abc@xyz.com");mail.Subject = TextBox3.Text;mail.Body = TextBox4.Text;
mail.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;mail.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(TextBox1.Text);  SmtpServer.Send(mail);